# Android studio, after user click go to (A)page, restart apps will open (A) page

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

i am beginner in Android Studio. I know there was a function called SharedPreferences, but i did not know how to use it.

Can anyone explain to me how to use it as i given the example above.

Comment: btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ????;
            }
        });
private void storepage(???){
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("storepage", MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("pages", ???);
    editor.apply();}
   private void getpage(){
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("storepage", MODE_PRIVATE); sharedPreferences.getString(???);

Comment: can anyone tell me what should i inserted on (????)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't  quite get what you said but here is as much as i know:
You first make a Sharedpreference Object and then a Sharedpreferemce editor object like this
    Sharedpreference s=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreference("a name for your preference",and the mode that actually is zero 0);
    Sharedpreference.Editor ed=s.Edit();
The rest is easy for editing values use ed.putboolean ,ed.putString ,ed.putInt and more and at last use ed.commit() or ed.Apply() to apply the changes you have made and for getting the values use s.getString
The concept is very easy Editor for editing and Sharedpreference for getting value

And at last when puting values the concept is like this 
    ed.putValue(key,value);
Key is the name and value is the value 
And for getting keys the concept is like this
    S.getValue(key,defvalue)
Key is the name of the variable that you saved value in it and the def value comes when that key is empty both are String types
 And at last jf you are so new to android studio first learn basic things like lifecycle and much more it will help you alot.

Hope you get it

****EDITED**** but if you are talking about going to new activity from one activity that is not the Sharedpreference that is the Intent and startActivity by the way java hasn't got functions it has methods.

Comment: For example, i have a button to bring user to chinese language. After i restart the application main page will be the chinese version instead of default language.